# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore]: runc

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a docker image based on this repo:

https://github.com/TechPreacher/iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders

But the repo seems to have error in the docker files:

When I build the image using right click on Module.json Build IoT Edge Module Image I get this output:

```
[+] Building 2.5s (9/11)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.arm32v7                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 40B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim-arm32v7                                                                                                           2.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk                                                                                                                                               1.2s
 => [build-env 1/4] FROM docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk@sha256:ce3e3bd9286e81e9b289d8fceae9e5e51e51b9dc962076cc0c96452445aec13a                                                                               0.0s
 => [runtime 1/3] FROM docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim-arm32v7@sha256:689e282b9b64cc86702309ae29f471b7ac588085f458a5ef3bc358071a527f2d                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build-env 2/4] WORKDIR /DecoderCollection/                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [build-env 3/4] RUN dotnet restore                                                                                                                                                                      0.5s
------
 > [build-env 3/4] RUN dotnet restore:
#9 0.429 MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

One screenshot of my folder structure:

[image]

I tried running the docker build command inside the DecoderCollection folder which has the .csproj but its the same error.

docker file@

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env

#WORKDIR /DecoderCollection/
#COPY ./Samples/DecoderSample ./

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim-arm32v7 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /build/Samples/DecoderSample/out/* ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SensorDecoderModule.dll"]
```

Comment: Please post formatted code rather than screenshots. Screenshots break search, copy and paste, and are less accessible.

Comment: the code is in the link!